# IIS Rewrite with Rewrite Map

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm struggling with IIS Rewrite maps. My map is simple:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect rule for MigratedSites" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.+)(/.+)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{MigratedSites:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://tgt.sp.lab{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="MigratedSites">
                <add key="/sites/apple" value="/sites/apple" />
                <add key="/sites/banana" value="/sites/banana" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
```

What I have managed is http://src.sp.lab/sites/apple is redirected to http://tgt.sp.lab/sites/apple, and the same for banana, but what it doesn't do is redirect http://src.sp.lab/sites/apple/SitePages.Home.aspx to http://tgt.sp.lab/sites/apple/SitePages.Home.aspx

Anything I add after apple or banana causes the redirect to stop working. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: That's just how a rewrite map work, and it only performs exact matching on the keys (`/sites/apple` but not `sites/apple/SitePages.Home.aspx`). If you want pattern matching, create individual rewrite rules instead.

Comment: Thank you for that; I haven't used IIS URL Rewrite before and I thought that the Rewrite map would be an ideal solution as I'm going to be migrating 100s of sites, but without the ability to match to whatever comes after the pattern I will have to use Rewrite rules instead.